# Python read stdin continually and effectively

Tags: python-2.x

I'm trying to design a game in the terminal in Python2.7. In my game class I have this:

```
from board import board
from sys import stdin
from termios import tcgetattr as getat, tcsetattr as setat, TCSADRAIN
from tty import setraw

class game:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.board = board() # p1, p2
        self.fd = stdin.fileno()
        self.old_settings = getat(self.fd)
        self.buffer = kwargs.get("key buffer", 4)
        if type(self.buffer) is not int or self.buffer < 4:
            self.buffer = 4


    def wait(self):
        keys = bytearray()
        while True:
            setraw(self.fd)
            keys.insert(0,stdin.read(1))
            setat(self.fd, TCSADRAIN, self.old_settings)
            #'h'=104, 'j'=106, 'k'=107, 'l'=108, 'd'=100, '\x1b'=27, '['=91
            if keys[0] == 104 or keys[0] == 68 and keys[2] == 27 and keys[1] == 91:
                print "left"
            elif keys[0] == 106 or keys[0] == 66 and keys[2] == 27 and keys[1] == 91:
                print "down"
            elif keys[0] == 107 or keys[0] == 65 and keys[2] == 27 and keys[1] == 91:
                print "up"
            elif keys[0] == 108 or keys[0] == 67 and keys[2] == 27 and keys[1] == 91:
                print "right"
            elif keys[0] == 3:
                break
            else:
                print repr(keys[0])
```

I threw it together very quickly, and it's not much, but it makes stdin "raw" until it receives a char and then flips it back so that it doesn't mess stuff up (found [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892/)). The only problem with this is there are a lot of things that aren't always just one character. For example the up-arrow key in decimal is 27,91,65 or in hexadecimal 0x1b,0x5b,0x41 or as bytes "\x1b\x5b\x41". Those are three different bytes/chars. If you look at the code above you can see that I partially get around this, but it would take a *lot* of extra energy if I wanted to figure out if the user pressed the `[Home]` key, which is 4 bytes. Harder still (actually this appears impossible to decipher if the arrow key is pressed or not), the user could have hit `[Esc]` (27 or 0x1b or "\x1b") then `[` (91 or 0x5b or "\x5b") and then `A` (65 or 0x41 or "\x41"). That is also true for all of the other arrow keys, most of the function keys the `[Home]`, `[Pg Up]`, `[Pg Dn]`, `[End]`, etc. keys, as well. (I have tested hitting `[Esc]`, `[`, `A`, and it works - i.e. it interprets this as `up`).

Almost everything can read arrow keys, function keys, home/end/pg keys, so why shouldn't I be able to as well? Is this just something that wasn't developed in Python(2)? I am really hoping that someone can provide either a better way or read stdin or a better way of interpreting it.

Comment: Have you considered using the curses library?

Comment: @JonKiparsky Sort of; I glanced at it a couple weeks ago, but I kind of want to do it myself. I know a thing or two about Ansi escape sequences, so it would be fun. I did **not** know, however, that curses lets you read from stdin. I guess it would have to, though.

Comment: I can understand that, but you have to decide whether you want to be making a game or whether you want to make the tools to make a game with. It's fine if you want to do the latter, but it should be a conscious decision.

Comment: @JonKiparsky But I want my cake before and after I have eaten it. :) It is a very valid point, moreover. It appears as though I have sort of gotten around it above, but I was just wondering if there was a better way of doing it. I'll take a look at curses more in depth, but I don't know if I will end up using curses.

Comment: Also, as a side note, I could always keep the keys very simple. As you can see above, the up/down/left/right keys have the "hjkl" left,up,down,right vim-style key sequences as well as the complex "\x1b[..." arrow keys.

Comment: @JonKiparsky **And** I was just playing around with curses; it does the *same* exact thing as above... if you do `window = curses.initscr()` and then `while True: print repr(window.getch())` or `while True: print repr(window.getkey())`, it still only returns each byte not the the whole key code.